# Getting OOM issue while converting byte stream of Zip files

Tags: java, io, zip

Im getting Exception while converting Zip files into bytestream. File size is : 80 MB

Code:

```
 File zipFile = new File("abc.zip");
 byte[] zipbyte = new byte[(int) zipFile.length()];    //Line #: 107
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
fileInputStream.read(zipbyte);

return zipbyte;
```

Exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sample.ZipUtil.doZip(ZipUtil.java:107)
```

Comment: Dear, you are trying to hold in memory byte array with length of 80mb. This is the core of your problem. Use streams instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to hold in memory byte array with length of 80mb. This is the core of your problem. You should use streams instead, something like this:

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(zipFile); 
     ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(...)) {
     (...)
    IOUtils.copy(is, zos);
     (...)
}
```

Comment: Finally I need byte stream for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough available memory to instanciate an array of `zipFile.length()` length.

Without any major change in the way you read the zip file, you should increase your heap space memory with the JVM options: `-XmxX`. For instance `-Xmx1G` (`1G` standing for 1GB).